# comparar números en una lista

Tags: java

Realizando una actividad, me he cruzado con un método que dice:

`getValoresIntervalo(int menor, int mayor)`: Este método tiene que devolver un `arrayList` con los números del `arrayList` atributo de la clase (mostraré a continuación) que están comprendidos entre menor y mayor, ambos incluidos.

He utilizado una variable auxiliar para realizar la operación pero ando un poco perdido. A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Muchas gracias.

**Clase DatosEnteros**:

```
public class DatosEnteros { 

//Atributo de clase: ArrayList de tipo Integer:
public ArrayList<Integer>array=new ArrayList<>();


public void llenar() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        array.add(rnd.nextInt());
    }
}

public void mostrarArray () {
    for (Integer integer : array) {
        System.out.println(integer.toString()+ "\n");
    }
}


public ArrayList<Integer>getValoresIntervalos(int menor, int mayor) {
   ArrayList<Integer>arrays=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer integer : array) {
        if(menor>mayor) {
            int aux = mayor;
            menor=mayor;
            mayor=aux;
        }
            arrays.add(integer);
       }
        return arrays;
}


}
```

Llamada desde el **main**:

```
public class Ejercicio1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatosEnteros de = new DatosEnteros();
    de.llenar(); 
    de.mostrarArray(); 
    System.out.println("Números del ArrayL atributo"
            + " de la clase \n comprendidos entre el"
            + " menor y mayor: " + de.getValoresIntervalos(199571757, 1709606034));

}


}
```

Lo que muestra en pantalla: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. No acabo de entender el problema ¿Tienes que crear el método `getValoresIntervalo(int menor, int mayor)` con la funcionalidad que se te indica y eso es lo que no está funcionando? Y tengo una duda ¿por qué usas números tan grandes, no podrías generar números aleatorios entre 0 y 100 por ejemplo?

Comment: Buenas! El método en cuestión dice que he de recorrer el arrayList y preguntar si los valores están comprendidos entre esos dos pasados, de ser así, los meto en un nuevo arrayList que debo devolver. El hecho de usar números tan grandes es porque me lo pide el ejercicio. No obstante acabo de modificar el método llenar() como me has comentado, pero con números del 0 al 20:  public void llenar() { 
                                       for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                                           array.add(i);
        }
    }

Comment: Modificar el `for` no altera el valor del número aleatorio, solo cambia el número de repeticiones del bucle. Si quieres definir un rango a la hora de generar un número aleatorio puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma: `int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;` Siendo `max` el número más alto y `min`el más bajo. Como bien ya han indicado en una respuesta el problema está en el `if(menor>mayor)` ya que nunca llega a verificar si el número del `arrayList` está dentro del intervalo.

Comment: Tienes razón Ferni, y la mejor forma de comprobarlo es la de hacerlo con números inferiores, ya que sino es complicado ver si está correcto o no. Ahora si puedo volver a generarlos como me pedían en la actividad. Respecto al if del método, ya he realizado también la modificación necesaria. Funciona bien. Muchas gracias por las ayudas mostradas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien el problema, diría que el fallo está en el if dentro del for each del método, ya que en ningún momento estás comparando integer con menor o mayor, es decir, estás metiendo todo el array en arrays (lo único que haces en el if es cerciorarte de que menor es menor que mayor). Me parece que ese if lo deberías hacer fuera del for each, y cambiar el for each por:

```
for (Integer integer : array) 
{
            if(integer<=mayor && integer>=menor) 
            {
                 arrays.add(integer);
            }

 }
```

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias por la atención. Un saludo.